# Why is session undefined inside _app component

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to conditionally include a `<Layout>` component based on whether a user is logged in or not. Naturally, my first instinct is to do this inside the _app component, since the Layout applies to every page.

However, for some reason, it seems like `session` is undefined in the _app component, no matter what...
I guess by the time _app renders, the `SessionProvider` is not initialized? I don't really understand why that would be, or whether I'm doing something wrong.

```js
import { type AppType } from "next/app";
import { type Session } from "next-auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { api } from "../utils/api";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const MyApp: AppType<{ session: Session | null }> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      {/* if logged in, include layout component */}
      {session && (
        <Layout>
          A
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      )}
      {/* if not logged in, don't include layout component */}
      {!session && (
        <>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          {console.log(session)}
        </>
      )}
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default api.withTRPC(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how to check the session.

What you have to do is to access the session from your Layout :

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
const Layout = (props) => {
  const { status } = useSession();
//...
}
```

Then before returning the layout `jsx` you check if the user is not authenticated so you don't return the layout but only `props.children` :

```js
if(status !== "authenticated"){
return <>{props.children}</>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that I can't access `session` in the _app component? Why is it `undefined` ?

Comment: because the session lives in pageProps and since `MyApp` is the first component to mount so `session` is undefined there, however it will be provided to `SessionProvider` children when it recives data from `[...nextauth]` thats why we should get the session from SessionProvider's childrens(you can access it from server component using `getServerSession`  too). the same happen when you reload a page, the session will be undefined for a while  for the same reason. Check [this](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#custom-client-session-handling) to understand how you can deal with it